# PHP two-way merge sort

Tags: php, c++, sorting

I have two equal examples of two-way merge sort on C++ and PHP.
C++ example works fine but PHP doesn't.

Why php example doesn't work? Can't find an error:

```
function merge($m, $low, $mid, $high)
{
$i = $low;
$j = $mid+1;
$k = 0;
$tmp = array();

while (($i <= $mid) && ($j <= $high))
{
if ($m[$i] > $m[$j])
$tmp[$k++] = $m[$i++];
else 
$tmp[$k++] = $m[$j++];
}

if ($i <= $mid)
{
while ($i <= $mid)
$tmp[$k++] = $m[$i++];
}

if ($j <= $high)
{
while ($j <= $high)
$tmp[$k++] = $m[$j++];
}

for ($i = $low; $i <= $high; $i++)
$m[$i] = $tmp[$i-$low];

return $m;
}

function mergeSort($m, $low, $high)
{
if ($high > $low)
{
$middle = ($high+$low)/2;
mergeSort($m, $low, $middle);
mergeSort($m, $middle+1, $high);
merge($m, $low, $middle, $high);
}
}

$m = array(0,3,2,4);
$m = mergeSort($m, 0, 3);
echo $m[0]; // there null :(
```

C++ example, its works fine:

```
 int m[10];
 void merge(int low, int mid, int high)
 {
int i = low;
int j = mid+1;
int z = 0;
int tmp[10] = {0};

while ((i <= mid) && (j <= high))
{
    if (m[i] < m[j])
        tmp[z++] = m[i++];
    else
        tmp[z++] = m[j++];
}

if (i <= mid)
{
    while (i <= mid)
        tmp[z++] = m[i++];
    }

if (j <= high)
{
    while (j <= high)
        tmp[z++] = m[j++];
}

for (int a = low; a <= high; a++)
    m[a] = tmp[a-low];
}

 void mergeSort(int low, int high)
{
if (low < high)
{
    int middle = (high+low)/2;
    mergeSort(low, middle);
    mergeSort(middle+1, high);
    merge(low, middle, high);
}
return;
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    m[i] = rand()%101;

mergeSort(0, 7);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    Console::WriteLine("{0}", m[i]);
Console::ReadLine();
return 0;
}
```

I guess, there are recursion loops, because the page loading too long.
But not idea how to check it. 
What i do wrong?

Comment: php has built in merge sort functions written in c

Comment: Basically you need to debug the code, which is almost all wrong. The semantics of arrays and passing arguments by value are very different in PHP, you cannot just transfer similar-looking code from C++ and expect it to work.

Comment: That's not C++, and your indentation is _horrendous_. You just hard failed code review, were you in my team.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yeah it is not C++, its pascal

Comment: @FireForce: No, it's C++/CLI or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there are two distinct problems with your code.

The first is that in PHP the language automatically used floating point when it thinks that's needed. So your `$middle = ($high+$low)/2;` will result in valuves such as 0.5, 0.125, etc, and thus causes infinite recursion. Throw an cast to `int` on there:

```
 $middle = (int)(($high+$low)/2);
```

and it gives you more what you want.

Second problem is that you are using `$m = mergeSort(...);` but there is no return statement in the `mergeSort` function. Which is why `$m` is NULL when you get it back.

Comment: thank you a lot for that comments. I made it now, time of script execution has back to rate. But i still have problem with the code: I made $m array as global and removed it from function's arguments, but nothing happens with that array...I checked for functions executions - they works, but nothing changes (

Comment: So, you have added `global $m;` in relevant places?

Comment: I added `global $m;` before declaring of both functions and initialized it by `$m = array(1, 3, 2, 5);` after them.
At end of the script i wrote `echo $m[1];` and it returned 3 to me...but should to be 2

Comment: Sorry, but without seeing all of the code, it's very hard to say. I just made the changes you have described, and added a few more elements to the array (and "count($m)-1" instead of the hard-coded 3 in the initial call to mergeSort) and it works. Check what you are doing, and make sure you are not shadowing `$m` somewhere by having it as a global and an argument to a function, or some such.

Comment: Thats all of the code. Still doesnt work...strange. Anyway thank you a lot for help, have nice day:)

Comment: No, I mean without seeing it AFTER you have changed it, it's hard to say what you may have done wrong.